# SQL Switch/Case/between in where clause

Tags: sql-server

I tried searching around but couldn't find anything that would help me out.

```
SELECT COL1,* FROM TAB1 A
JOIN TAB2 b ON A.ID=B. ID 
INNER JOIN TAB3 C ON C.AsOf=A.AsOf
WHERE 
 B.AsOf BETWEEN
(
    CASE WHEN C.DayOfWeek = 7 AND C.IsCalendarMonthEnd = 'Y' 
          THEN  DATEADD(dd,-1,C.PreviousCalendarDay) AND DATEADD(dd,+1,C.AsOf)
    END
)
```

i am getting error like '**Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND''**
i need find dates between dates basid on case statment

if possible?

Comment: I suggest getting a grasp of at least basic syntax up front before writing code.

Comment: Update Query: SELECT COL1,* FROM TAB1 A JOIN TAB2 b ON A.ID=B. ID INNER JOIN TAB3 C ON C.AsOf=A.AsOf WHERE B.AsOf BETWEEN ( CASE WHEN C.DayOfWeek = 7 AND C.IsCalendarMonthEnd = 'Y' THEN DATEADD(dd,-1,C.PreviousCalendarDay) AND DATEADD(dd,+1,C.AsOf) END )

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, error messages from Oracle in particular (you don't say which database server you're using) can be maddeningly unclear about where the error lies.

The problem is here:

```
JOIN TAB2 b ON A.ID=B. ID AND
INNER JOIN TAB3 C ON C.AsOf=A.AsOf
```

You don't want the `AND` there.  It's a syntax error.

Comment: And the `AND` in the `CASE` is wrong too (`THEN  DATEADD(dd,-1,C.PreviousCalendarDay) AND DATEADD(dd,+1,C.AsOf)`)

Comment: i am using SQL serevr 2005.sorry i miss type my actuall qureyy like this.SELECT COL1,* FROM TAB1 A JOIN TAB2 b ON A.ID=B. ID INNER JOIN TAB3 C ON C.AsOf=A.AsOf WHERE   B.AsOf BETWEEN (     CASE WHEN C.DayOfWeek = 7 AND C.IsCalendarMonthEnd = 'Y'            THEN  DATEADD(dd,-1,C.PreviousCalendarDay) AND DATEADD(dd,+1,C.AsOf)     END )

Comment: Please revise your question then, so it shows your actual query.

Answer (score 1):

There's an issue with your `WHERE` clause. You can't specify both bounds of the `BETWEEN` operator in `CASE` in one go. Possibly what you meant it to be like is this:

```
…
WHERE C.DayOfWeek = 7
  AND C.IsCalendarMonthEnd = 'Y'
  AND B.AsOf BETWEEN DATEADD(dd,-1,C.PreviousCalendarDay) AND DATEADD(dd,+1,C.AsOf)
```

Comment: but i have more case statement in my actual query.in that case is it works?

Comment: @BhaskaravarmaDandu: Could you please provide an example?

Comment: SELECT A.* FROM TAB1 A
JOIN TAB2 B ON A.ID=B.ID 
INNER JOIN TAB3 C ON C.AsOf=A.AsOf
WHERE
 B.AsOf BETWEEN
(
 CASE WHEN c.DayOfWeek = 7 THEN  DATEADD(dd,-1,c.PreviousCalendarDay) AND DATEADD(dd,+1,c.AsOf)
 CASE WHEN c.DayOfWeek = 1 THEN  DATEADD(dd,-1,c.PreviousCalendarDay) AND DATEADD(dd,+1,c.AsOf)
 CASE WHEN c.DayOfWeek = 2 THEN  DATEADD(dd,-1,c.PreviousCalendarDay) AND DATEADD(dd,+1,c.AsOf)
 END
)

Comment: The equivalent in this particular case would be `… WHERE C.DayOfWeek IN (1, 2, 7) AND B.AsOf BETWEEN DATEADD(dd,-1,C.PreviousCalendarDay) AND DATEADD(dd,+1,C.AsOf)`, because both bounds stay the same for either value of `c.DayOfWeek`. In more complex case, where the bounds vary, you could re-write the filter like this: `… WHERE (c.DayOfWeek = 7 AND B.AsOf BETWEEN FromSomething AND ToSomething) OR (C.DayOfWeek = 1 AND B.AsOf BETWEEN FromSomethingElse AND ToSomethingElse) …` and so on.